# Tool or .reg for permanently disabling hibernate and sleep in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate, disk-encryption

I would like a way of disabling sleep and hibernate in Windows 10 so that the hibernate file (`hiberfil.sys`) is gone and that under no circumstances can Windows go into either mode? Going through menus and console commands is not ideal when you need to do it many times.

I'll be using an encrypted disk, and hibernate and sleep pose a large security threat to this.

Comment: is `powercfg -h off` as admin not sufficient to your needs? http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/delete-hiberfilsys-by-disabling-windows-hibernate-function/

Comment: That disables sleep too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Make a batch file with the following lines:

> powercfg -h off
>
> powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
>
> powercfg -change -standby-timeout-dc 0

Run the script as Administrator.

Of course, running the following script would re-enable sleep (after 30 min) and hibernate, which means your request that, "*under no circumstances* can Windows go into either mode," cannot be fulfilled.

> powercfg -h on
>
> powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 30
>
> powercfg -change -standby-timeout-dc 30

Comment: The need for administrator privileges to turn it back on again should mitigate most things I'm worried about. Thanks